# dynamic log filename with incoming post request data in Django logging

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

I am very new to Django. I have a use case wherein, I have to group a log filename from incoming post request json data

Example of post request json data

```
{
    "name": "kurt",
    "year_of_birth": 1996,
    "course": "Arts"
}
```

I want to have a filename 1996.log to be generated, so that I can have datas of all the students with year_of_birth 1996 logged in 1996.log

Example 2

```
{
    "name": "Mike",
    "year_of_birth": 1994,
    "course": "Science"
}
```

In this case log filename should be 1994.log

This way I want to generate log filname by year_of_birth and have logs logged in respective log file with respect to incoming post request data

views.py

```
from rest_framework import viewsets

import logging


student_logger = logging.getLogger("student_log")


class BlogViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        data = request.data
        print(f"\n############ data: {data} \n\n")
        student_logger.debug(data)
        return Response({"data": "logged successfully", "msg": "success"})
```

LOGGING in settings.py

```
LOGGING = {
    "version": 1,
    "formatters": {
        'student_formatter': {
            'format': '{levelname} {asctime} {pathname} {filename} {funcName} {lineno} {message}',
            'style': '{',
        },

    },
    "handlers": {
        "student_handlers": {
            "level": "DEBUG",
            "class": "logging.FileHandler",
            "filename": os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "logs/year_of_birth.log"), # want to change year_of_birth.log with incoming post request data's year_of_birth i.e 1996.log, 1994.log
            'formatter': 'student_formatter'
        }
    },
    "loggers": {
        "student_log": {
            "handlers": ["student_handlers"],
            "propagate": True,
            "level": "DEBUG"
        }
    }

}
```

How do I achieve it. Incase i am not clear about the question, Please let me know.

Thanks in advance